# How to pass a variable on the transform property style in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I try to pass a variable on the transform property style in react-native but it don't work. My code bellow :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Accelerometer, Gyroscope } from 'react-native-sensors';
import { sensors } from 'react-native-sensors';

export default class Sensors extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    rotate: 0
  }
}

render() {
  var degree = this.state.rotate;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.fleche}></View>
    </View>
  );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  fleche: {
    width: 5,
    height: 150,
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    borderRadius: 5,
    transform: [{ rotate: '' + this.state.rotate + 'deg' }],
 }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Compass', () => Sensors);
```

I don't know the way to pass the variable in the transform style. Currently, I have this error : undefine is not an object(evaluating 'this.state.rotate').

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
render(){
    const transform = [{ rotate: this.state.rotate + 'deg' }]
    var degree = this.state.rotate
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={[styles.fleche, transform]} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes, a warning : Failed prop type: invalid prop 'style' of type 'string' supplied to 'View', expected 'objet'... And an other : Failed prop type: invalid prop 'style' of type 'string' supplied to 'RCTView', expected 'objet'...

Comment: sorry, I used wrong brackets, try again . I've updated ans.

Comment: Don't work again, but I found the solution : const transform = {transform: [{rotate: this.state.rotate + 'deg'}]} thank you anyway !

Comment: oh sry ! Nice work :) I've updated the ans. to make it acceptable.

Comment: But, i am getting blank white screen when i use transform property for style the component.